# Nested element not getting generated in knockout :foreach

Tags: razor, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="crs-wt-dropbox crs-wt-dropbox-row" data-bind="foreach :rowCols">
   <span class="crs-wt-drop-item" data-bind="text: text"> <a class="close-ico" href="#" > </a></span>
</div>
```

where `foreach :rowCols` rowCols will updated dynamically:
so, after adding few values to `rowCols`, it has generated following code

```
<div class="crs-wt-dropbox crs-wt-dropbox-row" data-bind="foreach :rowCols">
<span class="crs-wt-drop-item" data-bind="text: text">Account</span>
<span class="crs-wt-drop-item" data-bind="text: text">Account number</span>
</div>
```

but I'm wondering why it doesn't generated any anchor tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data-bind="text: text" binding replaces inner content of the span. So you get "Account" text instead of the anchor tag.

#### Update 1

If I've understood your requirements right, to overcome this behavior you should move the "text" binding into the anchor element:

```
 <span class="crs-wt-drop-item"><a class="close-ico" href="#" data-bind="text: text"></a></span>
```

#### Update 2

It seems to me like this code snippet solves the task:

```js
var model = { rowCols: [ { text: 'Item 1'}, { text: 'Item 2'} ] }

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="crs-wt-dropbox crs-wt-dropbox-row" data-bind="foreach: rowCols">
   <span class="crs-wt-drop-item"><a class="close-ico" href="#" data-bind="text: text"></a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: so how can I get anchor tag with that?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help @TSV

Comment: @MokshShah Can you provide jsfiddle, illustrating your problem?